JSON Extraction in SQL
I'm trying to use SQL in DBeaver to query a column containing some JSON values.
The JSON object has the following structure:
[
   {"key":"screen_name", "value":{"string_val":"Dashboard","int_val":1} },
   {"key":"screen_type", "value":{"string_val":"Page1", "int_val":2} },
...
]

Let's say, I'd like to extract the screen name "Dashboard"; how do I do that?
I've tried all of the below:
SELECT get_json_object(mycolumn, '$.key')

SELECT get_json_object(mycolumn, '$.value')

SELECT get_json_object(mycolumn, '$.screen_name')

SELECT get_json_object(mycolumn, '$.key.screen_name')

SELECT get_json_object(mycolumn, '$.key.screen_name.value')

SELECT get_json_object(mycolumn, '$.key.screen_name.string_val')

SELECT get_json_object(mycolumn, '$.key.screen_name.value.string_val')

SELECT get_json_object(mycolumn, '$.screen_name.value')

SELECT get_json_object(mycolumn, '$.screen_name.string_val')

SELECT get_json_object(mycolumn, '$.screen_name.value.string_val')

None of these worked (they output [NULL] in the SQL output).
I've also tried extracting the value(s) according to this tutorial, but to no avail.
Does anyone know how to do so? Thanks!

@DarkBee unfortunately no, because I'm trying to extract the value instead of breaking them down. I've tried a similar method with that post, as outlined here: https://www.wagonhq.com/sql-tutorial/values-from-nested-json/ which also did not work

I've added this info in the question. Please revise the wording and change where necessary

Which dbms are you using?

@jarlh the dbms is postgre sql

jsonb_path_query(mycolumn, '$[*] ? (@.key == "screen_name").value.string_val')->>0

To achieve this, you can modify your queries as follows:
SELECT JSON_VALUE(mycolumn, '$.key') AS keyJson from [tableName]

note that all your table records must be in JSON format; otherwise, you will encounter a query exception error in SQL.

Hi, unfortunately, this didn't work; I received "Encountered: A reserved word cannot be used as an identifier: JSON_VALUE" for some reason (it's not "exception error", as you've mentioned). Seems that it interprets JSON_VALUE as an identifier for some reason... but strangely get_json_object was understood as a reserved word instead of as an identifier, and at least gave the "NULL" output, as I've mentioned in the post.
